# restrain VSTS users from seeing other user's tickets

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I can't figure out if it possible and how it can be done to allow *certain* users in a Visual Studio Team Services project to see *only* the work items they created, instead of them all.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: I don't think this is supported out of the box, because VSTS is positioned as a tool for collaborative work, not as a Helpdesk system. It might be possible to experiment with area paths permissions (for instance, each 'certain' user creates work items into 'personal' area paths, and permissions are tweaked accordingly), but that sounds like a maintenance hell.

Answer (score 0):

For now, there is no ways to set permissions for a user to only view work items which were created by oneself.

It's only available to set permission based on **Iterations** and **Areas** for now.

But there has an user voice [field level security permissions](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32818474-field-level-security-permissions) which suggest similar feature, you can vote and follow up.

And the features in below two user voices have already added in our backlog, when the features are archeived, it can also benefit the situation you met:

[Hide Work Item Types (WITs) based on permission/security group](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/2085675-hide-work-item-types-wits-based-on-permission-se)

[Add ability to hide/mask fields in a work item based on security/permissions](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/2088177-add-ability-to-hide-mask-fields-in-a-work-item-bas)

Answer (score -1):

This is not supported. It used to be in the on-prem product a long time ago in the "Work item only view", but that has been removed in favour of the Stakeholder view.

Comment: I can't make it prettier. The tool had no way to hide items from other users. Only a custom built ui that uses the rest api can achieve this, but that's not a supported feature is it.